# generate sonar sonar-project.properties on the fly

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-3, sonarqube-scan

I am working in a big multi-module java maven project & my work is to setup reporting `sonarQube` issue at in the pull request of `bitbucket` after the build.

I have created the `sonar-project.properties` according to the project structure, setup the job in `jenkins`, so far this is working properly.

Now the problem is, as this is the parent of a lot of other projects, lots is new modules/sub-modules kept getting added in the project. Every time there is new module, the `sonar-project.properties` have to be modified accordingly. Although that is expected, but its forgotten sometimes.

This is the reason I was thinking of, is there a way to generate the `sonar-project.properties` on the fly before sonar-scanner starts executing.

This is the project structure we are following.

```
project-root/
    moduleA/
    .
    .
    moduleB/
    submoduleOfmoduleB/
    moduleC/
        submoduleOfmoduleC
        .
```

Is there any way to generate the `sonar-project.properties` by reading the pom files or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `sonar-project.properties` at all.  You can use the [sonar-maven-plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) with some standard properties in your pom and new projects are added automatically.

We use the following settings

```xml
<sonar.host.url>http://sonar:9000</sonar.host.url>
<sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
<sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
<sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec, target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
<sonar.exclusions>file:**/generated-sources/**,file:**/pom.xml,file:**/node_modules/**</sonar.exclusions>
```